# Add data to ModelForm object before saving

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Say I have a form that looks like this:

**forms.py**

```
class CreateASomethingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Something
        fields = ['field2', 'field3', 'field4']
```

I want the form to have these three fields. However my `Something`class also has `field1`. My question is - how do I add data to `field1`, if I am not using the `ModelForm` to collect the data. I tried doing something like this, but it isn't working and I am unsure on the proper way to solve this:

**views.py**

```
def create_something_view(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        # Create an object of the form based on POST data
        obj = CreateASomething(request.POST)
        # ** Add data into the blank field1 ** (Throwing an error)
        obj['field1'] = request.user
        # ... validate, save, then redirect
```

The error I receive is:

```
TypeError: 'CreateAClassForm' object does not support item assignment
```

In Django, what is the proper way to assign data to a `ModelForm` object before saving?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
form = CreateASomething(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.field1 = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you - a silly mistake on my end using a list access call to get an object's attribute.

Comment: For class-based views you can also [override the form_valid method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) to add this kind of information, then call `super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite the save method of the form to achieve the same thing?

Comment: What about if the field is a required field?  It never makes it to form_valid().

Comment: @trpt4him check my answer

Comment: Don't forget to call `form.save_m2m()` after `obj.save()` if your model has M2M fields.

Comment: Thank you, very cool! First it was giving me error that "Field is Required", but i sent that field's property "blank=True" in model.

Works like a charm

Comment: @Khateeb321 Setting a required field to `blank=True` in your model is probably not the best idea as it makes the semantics of your model unclear. A better solution when using class-based views would be to exclude your required field from the list of fields in the `ModelForm`, then the form will be valid and you can add the data for the required field in `form_valid()`.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes, the field might be required which means you can't make it past form.is_valid(). In that case, you can pass a dict object containing all fields to the form.

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
       data = {
        'fields1': request.user,
        'fields2': additional_data,
       }
       form = CreateASomethingForm(data)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.commit(save)
```

Comment: How might you handle this if say fields1 is an object you search for? I receive the error 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices'

Comment: Doesn't the additional_data variable come from the form itself?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways given by Django official
LINK : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Method 1]

```
author = Author(title='Mr')
form = PartialAuthorForm(request.POST, instance=author)
form.save()
```

Method 2]

```
form = PartialAuthorForm(request.POST)
author = form.save(commit=False)
author.title = 'Mr'
author.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more suitable way to add data especially used during testing:

First convert an existing entry into a dictionary with the `model_to_dict` function

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

...

valid_data = model_to_dict(entry)
```

Then add the new data into this dictionary

```
valid_data['finish_time'] = '18:44'
```

This works better than setting the value in the form

```
update_form.finish_time = '18:44'
```

Create the form with the valid data and the instance

```
update_form = UserEntryForm(valid_data, instance=entry)
```

Do any assertions you require:

```
self.assertTrue(update_form.is_valid())
entry = update_form.save()
self.assertEqual(
    entry.status,
    1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an answer that works for Class Based View considering the amount of answers out there related to old method view - I felt the simplicity of this approach should be out there.

Let's take the generic UpdateView - and should also work for the generic CreateView

```py
# Edit my_app/views.py

from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from my_app.models import MyModel

class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Note the instance after form.
        # Simply assigning the field on the form won't work.
        # nothing will complain, but it will not save. 
        # Assign the data to form.instance
        form.instance.updated_by_user = self.request.user
        super().form_valid(form)
```