# add data to admin modelform inline object before saving

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In relation to the question below, how would I do this for the django admin?

[Add data to ModelForm object before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126983/add-data-to-modelform-object-before-saving)

Example:

```
class FooInlineModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField()
    secret = models.CharField()


class FooInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FooInlineModel
        exclude = ('secret',)        


class FooInline(admin.TabularInline):
    pass


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FooInline,)
```

This logically triggers an IntegrityError because secret is submitted NULL, how do I manually populate the field in one of the admin methods? e.g.

```
class ???:
    def ???:
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.secret = 'stackoverflow'
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright I found the method, for those interested:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (FooInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)

        for instance in instances:
            if isinstance(instance, FooInlineModel):
                instance.secret = 'stackoverflow'
                instance.save()
```