# Saving Django Forms to DB

Tags: django

I'm learning about the [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) helper, and it is my understanding that best practice for form validation will be simply saving the form to a DB model object after simple code like so:

```
def my_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return redirect somewhere

     else:
        form = MyForm()

return render(request, 'mysite.html', {'form': form})
```

However, there is extra data I would like to add to this model object that isn't explicit in the form.  For example, what if I wanted to add a date stamp to the object, generated on server side?  How do I go about saving more information into the same model object, and what are the best practices for doing so?

Comment: What do you mean with 'more data'? More fields to a model?

Comment: Call save with `commit=False`. There are hundreds of examples on SO.

Comment: By more data I mean more fields.  Say I have a field in my model that is date time created, but I want to generate that date on server-side, not through the form.  How to I add these extra fields to the model object in the DB afterwards?

Comment: Ok, I've found commit-false, thank you Daniel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add data to ModelForm object before saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126983/add-data-to-modelform-object-before-saving)

Answer (score 0):

For trackin creation/modification dates you could use the 'DateTimeField':

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

`auto_now_add` inserts the current `datetime`when creating a new object, while `auto_now` does the same when updating.

For more specific logic you could use the `post_save` or `pre_save` signals, or override the `save` method.

```
# overriding save
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field = 'whatever'
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

.

```
# using signals
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def message_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.my_field = 'whatever'
```